# Personal meters & tools - C# or VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-7

I'm sure a lot of people around here tried [Rainmeter](http://www.rainmeter.net) or [Google desktop](http://desktop.google.com/). They are nice but I never felt comfortable using them on my desktop, either because they ate too many space or aren't much flexible in terms of settings and stuff that can be grabbed from the Webs.

So I thought I'd make my own personal tools.

It's intended for Windows 7. What language, VB or C#, should be easier to implement this kind of stuff (small panels with no borders/frames, small memory usage if possible) based on experiences of people?

Cheers!

Comment: This have access to the same APIs; this is the same as the perennial C#/VB.NET question (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629833/what-shall-i-use-vb-net-or-c-for-desktop-application)).

Comment: This stuff is done in C++.  The guy that did Rainmeter knows the Win32 API really well.  Quite hard to replicate in either of your preferred languages, lots and lots of pinvoke.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input!
@Hans: It won't be as complex hehe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing inherently different about C# or VB.Net that is going to make this task any easier.  They are both equally suited to the task, have access to the same APIs and have similar performance characteristics.

Just choose the language you are most comfortable with.  That will have the greatest impact on the ease in which this application is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a difference, since it's a .NET framework anyway, so same gui features and I think the same performance/memory usage. Go with the one you are more familiar coding with.